# C error: pointer expected

Tags: c

I made a simple program in C that finds if a number is prime. I am new to C and decided to try to use scanf instead of hardcoded numbers to check. When I run my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0
int main(){
  //I am going to check if the "checking" variable is a prime
  int checking;

  scanf("%d",checking);

  //"stopper" is where the for loop will stop
  int stopper = checking**0.5 + 1;

  //"found" will show if I have found something bad
  bool found = false;

  for (int i = 2; i < stopper; i++)
  {
    if (checking % i == 0){found = true; break;}
  }

  if (!found) {printf("it is prime");}
  else {printf("it is not prime");}

}
```

when I try to compile this with TCC it gives the error (primes.c is the name of the document)

```
primes.c:12 error: pointer expected
```

I don't know how to fix this.

EDIT: I just made stopper = checking/2 and the program crashes

Comment: `typedef int bool;`  why not use `stdbool.h`?

Comment: `scanf("%d",checking);` --> `scanf("%d",&checking);`

Comment: `I don't know how to fix this.`...homework dumping attitude detected. Please do basic research before asking on SO.

Comment: Did you mean `int stopper = checking*0.5 + 1;` instead of `int stopper = checking**0.5 + 1;`?

Comment: @hexidian There are a lot of errors in your code. `scanf` input is wrong. `int stopper = checking**0.5 + 1;` is wrong. You cannot have double multiplication. `if !found` parentheses are not present. Please correct your syntax. These are just basic issues which will be solved once you learn the syntax.

Comment: I think he means sqrt(checking)...

Comment: This isn't Fortran. In place of `checking**0.5`, I suspect you mean `sqrt(checking)` or `pow(checking, 0.5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `int stopper = checking**0.5 + 1;`

line 12... what do you expect the `**` operator to do?
A `*` typically performs a multiply, or dereferences a pointer.
The compiler could be interpreting it as follows:

```
int stopper = checking * (*0.5) + 1;
```

Of course, trying to dereference a float (`*0.5`) is bad / impossible, hence the error.

Did you mean:

- instead of `**`, you meant `*` (multiply)
- instead of `**` (not a C operator), you meant `pow()` (raise to the power of)

You also need to be specific - even if you're an expert at [precedance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the reader may not be, and you may well be wrong.

If you're not sure what's going on, use braces to be specific, which of the following do you mean?

- `int stopper = checking * (0.5 + 1);`
- `int stopper = (checking * 0.5) + 1;`
- `int stopper = pow(checking, 0.5) + 1;`
- `int stopper = pow(checking, 0.5 + 1);`

If you are indeed after the square root, then as @JeremyP says, invert your thinking - multiply is much less costly than `pow()`:

```
for (int i = 2; i * i <= checking; i++)
```

Comment: No by `**` he meant "raise to the power of". He's trying to get the square root of `checking`

Comment: oh, wow. that's for python not C. sorry about the stupid question, I'm an idiot

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your program:

(1) **Replace**

`int stopper = checking**0.5 + 1;`

**with**

`int stopper = checking*0.5 + 1;`

(2) **Replace**

`scanf("%d",checking);`

**with**

`scanf("%d",&checking);`

You should be good to after these corrections.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in operator to raise a number to the power of another number. There is a function to do that - also a square root function but you don't need them (see below).

```
x**y
```

is parsed as

```
x* (*y)
```

which is where your pointer error comes from

Instead of trying to find the square root, come at it from the other direction, change your for loop like this

```
for (int i = 2; i * i <= checking; i++)
```

Also, as others have said, the `scanf` is wrong.

```
scanf("%d",&checking);
//         ^- scanf needs a pointer to an int.
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `scanf` is wrong.
Use `scanf("%d",&checking);`

For finding the square root use `math.h` library for `sqrt` function.

```
int stopper = sqrt(checking) + 1;
```

There were a lot of typing mistakes in your code. Please, correct your syntax before asking a question.

[Ideone link for code](http://ideone.com/vEkXcg)